# Magento2 Installation Parse error unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR

Tags: magento2, php, magento-2.0, installation

I tried installing Magento2 today to try it out.

I ftp'd the zipped codebase from [github](https://github.com/magento/magento2) to my server and unpacked it, but when I try to run the installer I get the below error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in /public_html/magento2/app/bootstrap.php on line 64

Lines 59 down are:

```
/**
 * Require necessary files
 */
require_once BP . '/app/functions.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/autoload.php';
(new \Magento\Framework\Autoload\IncludePath())->addIncludePath(array(BP . '/app/code', BP . '/lib/internal'));
$classMapPath = BP . '/var/classmap.ser';
if (file_exists($classMapPath)) {
    require_once BP . '/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Autoload/ClassMap.php';
    $classMap = new \Magento\Framework\Autoload\ClassMap(BP);
    $classMap->addMap(unserialize(file_get_contents($classMapPath)));
    spl_autoload_register(array($classMap, 'load'), true, true);
}

if (!defined('BARE_BOOTSTRAP')) {
    $maintenanceFlag = BP . '/' . \Magento\Framework\App\State\MaintenanceMode::FLAG_DIR . '/'
        . \Magento\Framework\App\State\MaintenanceMode::FLAG_FILENAME;
    if (file_exists($maintenanceFlag)) {
        if (!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], explode(",", file_get_contents($maintenanceFlag)))) {
            if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli') {
                echo 'Service temporarily unavailable due to maintenance downtime.';
            } else {
                include_once BP . '/pub/errors/503.php';
            }
            exit;
        }
    }

    if (!empty($_SERVER['MAGE_PROFILER'])) {
        \Magento\Framework\Profiler::applyConfig(
            $_SERVER['MAGE_PROFILER'],
            dirname(__DIR__),
            !empty($_REQUEST['isAjax'])
        );
    }
}
date_default_timezone_set(\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface::DEFAULT_TIMEZONE);
```

Any ideas what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like an issue with your php version. It will need PHP 5.4 to work correctly. The reason is as follows.

> Class member access on instantiation works starting PHP 5.4

See the [github issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/621) from more information.